# Переход между окнами при регистрации - Android

Tags: android, activity, авторизация

Создал простейшую форму авторизации и возник вопрос, как сделать что бы открытые до этого страницы закрылись и открылась страница профиля(или другая)?

Comment: при каком действии должно происходить открытие страницы профиля (или другой), с вашего вопроса понятно что вы создали форму регистрации и хотите открывать страницу профиля. Уточните пожалуйста :)

Comment: При авторизации

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой способ это перейти на новую активити:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
```

Вместо **MainActivity.class** нужно указать класс нужной активити.

Чтобы закрыть текущую активити нужно вызвать **finish();**

Comment: А как закрыть все окна?

Comment: у вас и так будет только одна активити открыта, либо очистите стек при переходе.